# Looping statement that works in Windows 7 debug instructions won't work in DOSBox 0.74

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, dosbox

We had an activity about looping in assembly language. Our task is simple: display the numbers 0 to 9 with spaces in-between each number. I got the code to work in the command prompt using the 'debug' command in WINDOWS 7 in our school. My laptop is Windows 10 and I recently found out that there's no 'debug' command in the command prompt. So I tried writing my code in DOSBox 0.74 (latest, maybe). Every time i run it in DOSBox, the programs suddenly hangs up and then crashes. Here's the code

```
mov cx,0a
mov ah,02
mov dl,30
int 21
mov bl,dl
mov dl,20
int 21
mov dl,bl
inc dl
loop 0107
int 20
```

Can someone please explain me why DOSBox crashes?

Here is a sample pic of the working program which runs in cmd on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: Are you using `debug` in DOSBox? I ask because it is unclear how you are running your program in DOSBox.

Comment: Why you finish with `INT 20h` instead of `MOV AH, 4Ch; INT 21h`?

Comment: Why not use a label as the jump target for `loop`?

Comment: @i486 : `Int 20h` is perfectly fine when running a COM program as long as _CS_ still points to the base of the PSP. `ret` would have worked equally well

Comment: @PeterCordes : Because debug doesn't support labels

Comment: @MichaelPetch `INT 20h` is not wrong but is old style.

Comment: `int 20h` is a hold over from CP/M but is perfectly acceptable to use to exit a COM program. It can't be used to exit an EXE. The downside is that it doesn't return a value upon exit. `ret` (near) ends up doing an `int 20h` as the CS:0000h (in the PSP) is coded with an `int 20h` instruction as well. `ret` works because DOS places 0000h on the stack  before running the program.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the problem in DOSBox has more to do with how he is using it. Does he use Debug in Dosbox? (it isn't clear). The code looks perfectly fine, and I even pulled out DOSBox here (I have debug.com copied into it from an old DOS version) and it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe the BIOS of DOSBox is the problem. Does this work in VirtualBox?

Comment: I do know of one scenario where DOSBox will fail (and hang). If you copy DEBUG.EXE from a Windows environment, place the commands in a file and then use redirection to run it with something like `debug.exe < prog.txt` . It is best to use DEBUG.COM from an older version of DOS. I recently discussed that in this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236622/3857942)

Comment: You can cut & paste text from console windows by clicking on the icon in the upper left of the window, choosing the Edit -> Mark, selecting the tex and then pressing enter.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, I am using 'debug' in DOSBox

Comment: @m0vntain Did you copy it from your Win7 system or somewhere else?

Comment: @MichaelPetch i downloaded that 'debug' from another source. But right now, I'm trying the debug from your [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230551/dosbox-debug-exe-reads-file-processes-commands-incorrectly/36236622#36236622)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've downloaded and used the debug in your link and the program finally worked! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was also able to replicate this problem with MS-DOS 6.22's DEBUG.EXE. It appears to be a bug in DOSBox as it locks up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @RossRidge : I know that newer versions of DEBUG.EXE will be a problem. On some newer versions `int 20h` will even hang when run in DOSBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question isn't a duplicate of this other [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36230551/3857942) it seems to share certain similarities. Namely unexpected hangs or unusual behaviour. It would seem that `DEBUG.EXE` versions available for MS-DOS do not always function properly when run in DOSBox. This may be because DOSBox may not be 100% compatible emulating a real PC/Hardware(and DOS). This could result in some programs and/or OSes to not work as expected when used in DOSBox.

I have amended my previous [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36236622/3857942) to suggest a variety of MS-DOS `DEBUG.EXE` programs may not work properly when run under DOSBox. Ross Ridge confirms he can duplicate your problem with DOS 6.22's debugger when run inside DOSBox.

There is a version of `DEBUG.COM` that was released by [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) that seems to play well with DOSBox. I have made the FreeDOS version of [DEBUG.COM](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/DEBUG.COM) available for download from my website. Alternatively you can download the [ZIP File](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/DOS-Debug.shtml) from Softpedia and extract `DEBUG.COM`.

Comment: Note to clarify my statement I can replicate the problem with the MS-DOS 6.22 DEBUG.EXE when run under DOSBox. It works fine when used under MS-DOS 6.22 in a VM.

Comment: @RossRidge I was ambiguous, my answer meant to say that specifically they run improperly under DOSBox (They do run properly in their native environment - DOS). I implied it when I said that the reason for the issue was related to DOSBox compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

`AX` is a volatile register for DOS-interrupt `int 21h`. So the content of `AH=02h` will be overwritten by `INT 21h` calls. The only source I could find to reference to is a document about [Interrupt Services from the Mississippi State University](http://my.ece.msstate.edu/faculty/reese/EE3724/lectures/softint/softint.pdf) which states on page one:

> BIOS (and most DOS) ISRs Preserve Register Contents – Except ax

So in your code

```
int 21       ; alters AX
mov dl,bl    ; AH is undefined
inc dl       ; DL is increased correctly
loop 0107
```

you falsely assume that `AH` would still contain the value of `02h`. This is not (necessarily) the case.

So add a `MOV AH, 02h` before the loop statement and your program should execute less erroneous, because your `INT 21h` located at `0107` then would call the correct DOS-function `02h`.

Comment: BIOS/DOS is rather inconsistent with regards to calling convention. Although true AX is often clobbered it isn't always the case. [Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) is generally consider the Bible for DOS interrupts. In this case official docs use to say _AL_ and _AH_ were not touched. Ralf documents [INT 21h/AH=2](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) do show that _AL_ is destroyed and returns the character printed.I would say that this isn't the source of his problem. It ended up that the issue wasn't related to the code but was a problem with his `DEBUG` prg