# Stack issue in x86 assembly: triangle PROC faults on POP

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, dos

So I have this task to write a program that prints a chair built like a triangle with lines of chars.

When the user selects a number, in this example '4', it should look like this:

```
 1
 12
 123
 1234
 2  3
 3  2
 4  1
```

Well, for the triangle part I came up with this:

```
DATA SEGMENT   

  WELCOME DB 'PLEASE ENTER INTEGER BETWEEN 2 AND 9:$' 
  NEWLINE DB 13, 10, '$' 
  WRONG DB 10,13,'WRONG INPUT!',10,13,'$'

DATA ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT STACK
  DW 100 DUP (?)
SSEG ENDS

CODE SEGMENT

  ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA,SS:SSEG

  START:
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV DX,OFFSET WELCOME
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H 

    CMP AL,32H
    JL WRONG_INPUT
    CMP AL,39H
    JA WRONG_INPUT
    JMP TRIANGLE

  WRONG_INPUT:  
    MOV DX,OFFSET WRONG
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    JMP START

    MOV CL,AL
    SUB CL,30H 

  TRIANGLE:
    CALL NEW_LINE
    ;BL PRINTED NUM
    ;AL COUNTER NUM
    ;CL LOOP NUMBER

    XOR BH,BH
    XOR AH,AH
    XOR CH,CH
    MOV AL,32H
    MOV BL,32H 
    PUSH AX
    CALL NEW_LINE  

  COUNTERLOOP:

  CHECK_PRINT:
    MOV DL,BL
    MOV AH,2
    INT 21H
    INC BL
    POP AX
    CMP BL,AL            
    JBE CHECK_PRINT
    JMP NEXT_ROUND

  NEXT_ROUND:

    INC AL
    PUSH AX
    DEC CL
    MOV BL,32H
    CALL NEW_LINE   
    LOOP COUNTERLOOP 

  LEGS:
    ; TODO --- create 'legs'
  EXIT:    
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

  PROC NEW_LINE
    MOV BP,SP
    MOV DL, 0AH
    MOV AH, 2H
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0DH
    MOV AH, 2H
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,31H
    MOV AH,2H
    INT 21H
    RET
  NEW_LINE ENDP

CODE ENDS
END START
```

...but for some reason the `POP` gives me `00,00` on one time even though I used the `PUSH` before..
Do you have any advice?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are doing, but since you `POP AX` in the loop, if you go back via `JBE CHECK_PRINT` that means you are going to pop again without pushing. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Got it,thx. Appreciate the advice

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with the `stack` tag. If you hover your mouse over this, you'll receive the information, that a stack is a LIFO(last-in-first-out) data structure.

The problem with your code is, that you `PUSH` one value in and (possibly) `POP` several values out which messes up the stack. See, in `TRIANGLE:` you push one value to the stack:

```
PUSH AX
CALL NEW_LINE
```

But in `CHECK_PRINT:` you try to `POP` this one value (possibly) more than one time, `POP`ing other values from the stack:

```
CHECK_PRINT:
  ...
  POP AX
  CMP BL,AL            
  JBE CHECK_PRINT      ; !!! possibly POPping more than one time if BL >= AL
  JMP NEXT_ROUND
```

This may cause your problem. At least, it's *very* unsafe programming.

A solution to this may be saving `AX` before every `INT 21h` call. I had an answer/comment about that topic some days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677181/1305969). However, not messing up the stack and preserving the `AX` register should bring you closer to your desired solution.

So here are my suggestions:

- Remove the `PUSH AX` before the `CALL NEW_LINE`
- Remove the `PUSH AX` after the `INC AL` in `NEXT_ROUND`
- Remove the `POP AX` in `CHECK_PRINT`
- Surround your `INT 21h` call in `CHECK_PRINT` with `PUSH AX` and `POP AX`

  ```
  PUSH AX    ; added
  MOV DL,BL
  MOV AH,2
  INT 21H
  POP AX     ; added
  ```
- Modify your `NEW_LINE` PROC to

  ```
  PROC NEW_LINE
    PUSH AX        ; added
    MOV BP,SP
    ...
    POP AX         ; added
    RET
  NEW_LINE ENDP
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the information,will try to work this out..can I ask what would you do instead?