# ASM: INT 20 doesn`t work on Debug DOSbox

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, dos, dosbox

I've only done that and the window turns frozen while executing the program:

```
debug.exe
-a0100
073F:0100 MOV AX,0002
073F:0103 MOV BX,0004
073F:0106 ADD AX,BX
073F:0108 INT 20
073F:010A
-g
```

...and it fails. It doesn't fail if I try:

```
-g108
```

Because, it ignores "int20" and, of course, it doesn´t work with:

```
-g10A
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try int21/4c if you just want to terminate your program.

Comment: Did you try 20h instead of just 20?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez : debug.exe is pretty ancient - it doesn't take prefixes or suffixes to specify base. Everything is in hex.

Comment: You likely have a program called `debug.exe` .It was likely acquired from a 32-bit Windows distribution. Unfortunately `debug.exe` from Windows is known to have issues like this under DOSBox. You should delete `debug.exe` and download a version of `debug.com` for DOS. You can download it from my webserver at http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/DEBUG.COM

Comment: I have a suspicion we'll find that this question will probably be a duplicate (or a variant of) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230551/dosbox-debug-exe-reads-file-processes-commands-incorrectly

Comment: Instead of INT 20, try | MOV AX,4C00 | INT 21 | .

Comment: Definitely i had to use the debug.com file instead of debug.exe. Thanks for the file.