# How to properly run .txt file using dos debug (dosbox)?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I am using debug.exe program in dosbox. However, I am facing some difficulties while trying to run .txt or .asm files with debug.exe.

Here's my code (assembly), that I am trying to run

```
a200
db 50

a260
db 'Enter text' 0D 0A '$'

a100
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 260
int 21
mov ah, 0A
mov dx, 200
int 21
mov ah, 02
mov dl, 0d
int 21
mov ah, 02
mov dl, 0a
int 21
xor cx, cx
mov bx, 201
mov cl, [bx]
inc bx
mov dl, [bx]
cmp dl, 41
db 74 04 
mov ah, 02
int 21
db e2 f2
mov ah, 4c
int 21

n hello.com

r cx
500
w

q
```

The program always crash and I am not sure what could be wrong

Here is a screenshot of what I get every single time: [image]

Comment: Maybe it is end of line character issues. I assume you may be on Linux making/editing this text file and then using it in DOSBox? if so try `unix2dos filename` where filename is the text file name you are using.

Comment: I am doing everything on windows. My friend tried to run this code on his own computer (mac) and everything worked. I will try to look closer into end of line characters then.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this. What debug command line are you using to run this file. Something like `debug <filename` or something else? You said you are using debug.exe. What date and file size is that debug.exe (or is it debug.com)?

Comment: Yes, I am using `debug <filename` command line. I found same problem here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230551/dosbox-debug-exe-reads-file-processes-commands-incorrectly). I think the solution is to use version of debug.com.

Comment: It works now, I changed debug.exe with debug.com.